# android - use button to return to home screen

Tags: android, eclipse

In my app, I switch from one activity to another using a button configured with the code below:

```
startActivity(new Intent(ThirdActivity.this, FourthActivity.class));
```

My issue is that I'm struggling to configure button to go to the home screen rather to another activity. I know it might be a simple question but I'm a beginner at this.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

J

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to home screen as shown below. In the onClick method of the button write the following code:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

This intent will launch the launcher activity defined by the user in manifest.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `Activity#finishAffinity`, which kills this and all the activities in the same task below to the current. This should put the user to the home screen. This of course, will remove the state of your app, and maybe it is not what you want.

Take into account that this method appeared in api 16, but you can use the one in `ActivityCompat` to make it backward compatible.

If what you want is to keep the state of your app in the OS stack, the @Kesh1234 answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Feantury. What you described is what I'm looking for, however I can't seem to be able to apply it in context. I'm testing this on api level 8 (android 2.2), can you please explain what syntax I should apply where please ?

Thanks in advance



J

Comment: Use `ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(activity);`. For this to work use  android.support.v4 library